# How to Set Enter is ok on Textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a password textbox (Tbx1) and a Login button (Btn1). What code will i put where so that when the user 
inputs password and presses enter, Btn1 clickevents will be exucuted?

Comment: Set the accept button on the form to be Btn1

Comment: @Malcor, it worked. If u put it as an answer, ill accept asap.

Comment: @HenryGathigira what if you have other fields you want to check with the `enter` button against? The solution Malcor provided wont work and will run that method every time a user presses enter... You need to handle the `KeyPress` as `Weapon X` provided...

Comment: I get your point so clear @Zaggler. My case since its a login form i just needed to enter once. But stil as you say, Ill give Weapon X 9outof10 and Malcor 7outof10, and #takeiteasyMalcor.lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        fun()
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        fun()
 End Sub

Private Sub fun()
    MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

on Form Misc Properties set the accept button to be Btn1. Equally, you can set a cancel button too to be executed whenever the user presses Esc button.

Code version (through the constructor):

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.AcceptButton = Btn1
End Sub
```